# Using Observable.FromEvent with WebClient.DownloadProgressChanged

Tags: system.reactive

I'm attempting to use Reactive Extensions (Rx) to subscribe to `WebClient.DownloadProgressChanged`. As far as I can work out, because `DownloadProgressChanged` uses a custom delegate type, I need to use the really long-winded `FromEvent` overload:

```
var progress = Observable.FromEvent<DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler,
                                    DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs>(
                   h => new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(h), 
                   h => client.DownloadProgressChanged += h,
                   h => client.DownloadProgressChanged -= h);
```

However, the type of `progress` is `IObservable<IEvent>`, rather than the expected `IObservable<IEvent<DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs>>`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tested this and progress is of type

```
   IObservable<IEvent<DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs>>.
```

What version of Rx are you using?  I've just tested using the latest version (v1.0.2838.0)

Comment: Something older than that, although Reflector seems to show the correct return type. I'll try with the latest version.

Comment: Yep, works fine with v1.0.2838.0. Pity that the Rx MSI doesn't have the version number in the name...

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the version numbering scheme has changed since this post meaning that the latest at the time of this comment is: 1.0.11226 (in ymmdd format see here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/de1a62fa-abe8-4ea3-a653-1ff47b4d8d82 )